# Finding roots with Newton's method

Tags: roots

I have
$$
f(x)=x^7-12
$$
and need to find the roots with $\epsilon=0.0001$ accuracy. I have done the first steps but can't continue further. Here's what I've done:

Ive narrowed down the range where I there is a root and found those $x$ values:
$$f(1.4)=-1.45, f(1.43)=0.227$$
So I have $$\Omega a=[1.4;1.43]$$
$$f \prime(x) = 7x^6, f \prime \prime(x) = 42x^5$$
$${\frac{1}{|f \prime(x)|}} = max{\frac{1}{|7x^6|}} = (x=1.4) = {\frac{1}{52.7}} = a_1,$$
$${\frac{|f \prime \prime(x)|}{1}} = max|21x^5| = (x=1.43)= 125.5 = a_2$$
$$c = a_1a_2 = {\frac{125.5}{52.7}} = 2.38$$
Choose $$a = {\frac{1.4+1.43}{2}}=1.41$$
$$b=min(a, {\frac{1}{c}}) = min(1.41, {\frac{1}{2.38}})$$
The minimum is the value of $c$, and our teacher said that we need to apply such steps after which the minimum is the value of $a$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your method doesn´t look like the [Newton–Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Comment: Right, removed the tag. (There's no tag for Newton's method)

Comment: But what method is it?

Comment: It is Newton's method. Yeah it doesn't look like the one you showed but that's how we learned to do it.

Comment: Do you have a reference?

Comment: No I don't. Actually at the end of this method we don't find the root $x=x_n$, but rather the $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got what's wrong. I chose $a$ incorrectly. Should be
$$ a={\frac{1.43-1.4}{2}} = {\frac{0.03}{2}} = 0.015 $$
In that case we can have $b$ to be the value of $a$
$$b=min(a, {\frac{1}{c}}) = min(0.015, {\frac{1}{2.38}}) = 0.015$$